# Where is @moron?

Tags: discussion, user-accounts

math.SE user @Moron has been an incredible value to this site, but I cannot find a single entry from him any more.  Has his existence been purged from the system?  Or am I being moronic and not searching correctly?

Comment: Moron is here (in Hindi says translate.google) sometimes s/he also was $\Box\Box\Box$, at least on my machine...

Comment: Thank you for the kind words, Fixee.

Comment: @Aryabhata:But what happen to your [stackoverflow account](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5187664/generating-digits-of-square-root-of-2/5196280#5196280)?

Comment: @FoolForMath: I got it deleted.

Comment: @Aryabhata:Moron-->Aryabhata -->Ramanujan? ;)

Comment: @FoolForMath: No more name changes!

Comment: @Aryabhata:Good idea!We all love Moron!:)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Moron changed his name. I don't know if it would be appropriate to give the new name; anyway it is not hard to figure out with the appropriate Google search.

Comment: I don't know who he is but: thank you for changing your name!

Comment: @Mariano: You are welcome, Mariano :-) @Q i a, it is ok to divulge the new name, wait...

Comment: @Araya: I am kinda disappointed that you didn't just post an answer saying "I *am* Moron." `=p`

Comment: @Aryabhata: I'm pinging you since Willie mistyped... I also upvoted Mariano's comment.

Comment: @Willie/@J.M: :-)